# Javascript performance issue in IE

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

PFB Function of javascript.It is performing good in Chrome.But the performance is very poor in IE.If the function is taking 4ms in chrome,It is taking 170ms in IE.Someone please help me on this.
**Identified the issue is not because of Javascript.It is because of the ExecuteScript from webdriver** 
Is there any way to improve the performance in IE in this case?

```
 public string OnMouseMoveListner()
{
    string onMouseMove = @"  
    function OnMouseMove (event) 
    {
    window.onEscape=null;                                 
    window.isRefresh='set';
    var posX = event.clientX, posY = event.clientY;
    // displays the coordinates used for the elementFromPoint method                  
    // get the element that is located under the mouse                          y
    var overElem = document.elementFromPoint (posX, posY);
    if (overElem && overElem.tagName === undefined) 
    {   // in case of text nodes (Opera)
        overElem = overElem.parentNode; // the parent node will be selected
        window.control= overElem ;
    }                                                                      
    // the body and the html tag won't be selected
    if (overElem && overElem.tagName.toLowerCase () !='body' && overElem.tagName.toLowerCase () != 'html') 
    {                                 
        window.control= overElem ;                                   
    }  
    window.outerHeight=window.outerHeight;
    window.innerHeight=window.innerHeight;                                  
    }
    window.isRefresh='set';
    ";
    return onMouseMove;
}


  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript(js.OnMouseMoveListner());
```

Comment: what should this code do? `document.elementFromPoint` could be expensive I think.

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: I'm using IE11.I observed, when i try to run the js in notepad the performance is good in IE as well.But when I'm injecting the script to the driver.It behaves slowly.So i think issue is with   ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(js.OnMouseMoveListner());

Comment: IIRC the C# Selenium library has some weird speed issues. Have you tried setting it to 32-bit compilation?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser
Now i tried setting it to 32-bit and the performance is better comparatively.But not as fast as chrome

Comment: I'm using IE11,Windows10